# Upgrade git version osx

Tags: git, github

I have downloaded git 1.8.4.2 from github and install it into my OSX maverick and when I go and check the git version in Terminal it says 1.8.3.4 why? and when I go into the git website https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/examples/flaskr/flaskr.py I still can't use the open function. it says my git version is too old. why? do I need to do something more than installing it? do I need to write something in terminal? how can I download this code or this entire folder into my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can download the latest version of Git.

http://git-scm.com/download/mac

After that clone the repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask.git destinationfolder
```

For the **open** function you need a client on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The Readme.txt in the installation.dmg states:

> ## UPGRADING
>
> Simply download the latest Git installer, run the provided
>   uninstall.sh script, and then install as normal.

Besides that [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is always a nice alternative to install packages in an OS X environment.